# Getting webelement from dynamic text

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

firstli i write my scenario:

1. go http://demo.opencart.com/
2. search ipod
3. click add to compare in every found items

here is my code (java webdriver pagefactory)

searchresultspage (my object page)

```
@FindBy(id = "compare-total")
WebElement numberOfProductToCompare;

public void compareAllItems() {
    for (WebElement compareButtons: compareButton) {
        compareButtons.click();
    }
}

public void areAllItemsClickedCompare() {
    String text = numberOfProductToCompare.getText();
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

My main test class

```
@Test
public void addToCompare() {
    searchresultspage.compareAllItems();
    searchresultspage.areAllItemsClickedCompare();
}
```

i click all compare buttons and i want to get number from link `Product Compare (4)` but when i use `searchresultspage.areAllItemsClickedCompare();` then System.out.println(text); print me `Product Compare (0)`, even this method is after adding to compare (should be should be `Product Compare (4)`) Dont know what to do, some advice?

Comment: adding delay after `compareAllItems` might help

Comment: but what kind of delay??

Answer (score 0):

Think, the problem appears because the `compare-total` element is captured by Selenium on class instantiating, but when its content is updated on the page, it doesn't affect the captured value.
Try to capture the `compare-total` element only after all checkboxes were clicked:

```
public void areAllItemsClickedCompare() {
    WebElement numberOfProductToCompare = driver.findElement(By.id("compare-total"));
    String text = numberOfProductToCompare.getText();
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

Where `driver` is your `WebDriver` instance.

Comment: I tryed like this bus still was 0

Comment: @BV360 check an another approach then, maybe there is not enough time for the page to update. Use wait-until:
`new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(By.id("compare-total"), "Product Compare (4)"));`

Comment: will check in e momtent, but its not dynamic wait, whai if Product Compare will be ex. 7?

Comment: @BV360 in this case you'll get a TimeoutException. This approach is good if you want to test that an element has an exact value. And any other values are considered incorrect. If you just want to see a value, add: `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` to `addToCompare()` between two methods calling.

Comment: i got error
`org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for text ('Product Compare (4)') to be the value of element located by By.id: compare-total`